# Insert values to array with loop

Tags: javascript

I want to insert 15 random values to an array with a for loop. 
this my code, but its not working...

```js
var cardArray[]; //set up empty array

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var NumberCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    var NameCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

    cardArray[i] = "Number Card: " + NumberCard + " Name Card: "+ NameCard;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i+=2) {
    document.writeln(cardArray[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: *"it's not working"* is virtually meaningless and doesn't tell us anything about expectations or errors

Comment: `var cardArray[];` should be `var cardArray = [];`

Comment: Other than the syntax error mentioned by @AndrewLohr, it seems to work to me, although because the second loop increments by 2 it only prints half of the array

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining cardArray very well, it should be => `var cardArray = []`

Also, why are you doing `i+=2` in the second loop? You want to skip values? I changed it to `i++`

```js
var cardArray = []; //set up empty array

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var NumberCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    var NameCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

    cardArray[i] = "Number Card: " + NumberCard + " Name Card: "+ NameCard;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    document.writeln(cardArray[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you need to define the array first, like so!

```js
var cardArray = new Array(15); //set up empty array

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var NumberCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    var NameCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

    cardArray[i] = "Number Card: " + NumberCard + " Name Card: "+ NameCard;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i+=2) {
    document.writeln(cardArray[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your declaration. change

```
var cardArray[];
```

to

```
var cardArray = [];
```

```js
var cardArray = []; //set up empty array

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var NumberCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    var NameCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

    cardArray[i] = "Number Card: " + NumberCard + " Name Card: "+ NameCard;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i+=2) {
    document.writeln(cardArray[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cards = [];

function getRand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  cards.push("Number Card: " + getRand(1, 50) + " Name Card: " + getRand(1, 4));
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = cards[i];
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```